# How to linebreak Tab Header text into 2 lines?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have these Tabs and I want to be able to break down the text. For example instead of showing

> Soccer sport

I want to display it in 2 lines like this:

> Soccer
>
> sport

Does anyone knows how to make this happen?

Here's my code:

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-ngif-ucbbz8?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel header="Soccer sport">
    The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, overseeshis daughter's wedding. 
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Football sport">
    Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather parallels the young Vito
    grows.
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that with the current version of primeng you cannot do that.
With the latest version `7.0.5` you can supply a template for the header.
You could use:

```
<p-tabView>
<p-tabPanel>
<ng-template pTemplate="header">Soccer<br>sport</ng-template>
    The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, overseeshis daughter's wedding. 
</p-tabPanel>
<p-tabPanel>
<ng-template pTemplate="header">Football<br>sport</ng-template>
    Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather parallels the young Vito
    grows.
</p-tabPanel>
```

See the [modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-ngif-ogv8yt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a live demo.

FYI: if you want to update it apparently you'll also need to add `"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.1"` in your `package.json`